# Using const generics for functions

Tags: generics, rust

I've implemented this const generic trait that uses enums as a discriminant. In rust(stable) is there a way simplify this to just function specialisations. I appreciate right now we can't use enum values as a discriminant without nightly.

```
#[repr(u8)]
enum ReturnsType {
    Pct = 0,
    Log = 1,
    Total = 2,
}

// General   
struct ReturnsCalc<const T: u8>;
trait Returns {
    fn calc() -> f64;
}

// Specialisations - This works fine
impl Returns for ReturnsCalc<0> {
    fn calc() -> f64 {
        1.0
    }
}

impl Returns for ReturnsCalc<1> {
    fn calc() -> f64 {
        2.0
    }
}

// Test the call
fn some_function() -> f64 {
    ReturnsCalc::<0>::calc() + ReturnsCalc::<1>::calc()
}
```

Is there any way to do the same thing without the trait/struct as in:-

```
// General
fn calc<const N: u8>() -> f64;

// Specialisations - this doesn't work
fn calc<0>() -> f64 {
    0.0
}

fn calc<1>() -> f64 {
    1.0
}

// Test the call - this syntax is ok but the functions definitions arent
fn some_function_not_really_working() -> f64 {
    calc::<0>() + calc::<1>()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, why not have calc() as a method of ReturnsType?

Answer (score 1):

I found that one can do something like this. The only issue is that enum discriminant is lost so I had to put in a catch all at the end

```
fn calc<const N: u8>(window: &[f64], period: usize) -> f64 {
    match N {
        0 => (window[period - 1] / window[0]) - 1.0,
        1 => (window[period - 1] / window[0]) - 1.0,
        2 => (window[period - 1] / window[0]) - 1.0,
        _ => 0.0,
    }
}
```